# Notice: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to int in

Tags: php

Eu não entendo muito da parte de PHP e estou com um probleminha que não estou conseguindo resolver.

**ERRO no site**

```
Notice: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to int in orcamento.php on line 63
```

**Codigo referente a linha que esta dando erro**
Deixei marcado onde esta localizada a linha 63

```
    <?php
                    $sql_sb = "SELECT * FROM tbl_album WHERE ALBUM_STATUS = 1 ORDER BY ALBUM_NOME ASC";
                    $b = $con->query($sql_sb);
                    $nRows = $con->query($sql_sb);
                    $i = 3;
                ?>
                    <table>

                <?php
                **linha 63 aqui**   if($nRows > 0){
                        while($busca = $b->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                            if($i % 3 == 0){
                                echo '<tr>';
                            }
                                echo '<td>';
                                echo '<li><input type="checkbox" value="'.$busca['ALBUM_NOME'].'">'.$busca['ALBUM_NOME'].'</li>';
                                echo '</td>';
                            //echo '</tr>';
                            $i++;
                        }
                    }else{
                        echo "Não há produtos cadastrados";
                    }
                ?>
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá. Faça a seguinte alteração:

```
$nRows = $con->query($sql_sb);
```

Para

```
$nRows = $b->rowCount();
```

Se você perceber, $nRows tem o mesmo valor de $b, então ao invés de você recuperar o número de colunas, está re-executando a mesma query.

Comment: Nossa, que vacilo o meu, realmente não reparei nessa parte.

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou muito !!!

Comment: Bastante normal isso, ainda mais no começo. É assim que se aprende. Boa sorte nessa caminhada.